# PHP Implode to retrieve separate ID's?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm hoping someone can help.  I run the query below and then print the rows in a HTML table like this:

```
ARTIST 1, (Featuring) ARTIST 2, (and) ARTIST 3 
Song Title                                            YEAR       YT LINK
```

The trouble I'm having with the group_concat is that the index.php link (below) for ARTIST 1, ARTIST 2, ARTIST 3 now show artist.php?id=1,2,3.  I need to separate the ID's in order to link each ID to a separate artist.php for each artist using a link like this:

```
<a href="artist.php?id='.$row[3].'">'.$row[4].'</a>
```

How would I split the ID's and ARTIST NAMES up whilst being able to keep the table layout how it is? Do I use Implode within this query?

```
SELECT r.release_name, r.release_year, r.release_yt,
group_concat( a.artist_id ) AS artist_ids,
group_concat( a.artist_name ) AS artist_names
FROM tbl_release_artists ra
JOIN tbl_releases r ON r.release_id = ra.release_id
JOIN tbl_artists a ON a.artist_id = ra.artist_id
GROUP BY r.release_year, r.release_name, r.release_yt
ORDER BY artist_names, r.release_year, r.release_name ASC
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
explode(',', $_GET['id'])
```

This will return an array of IDs

EDIT:
Now that I understand your question -

```
$artist_ids = explode(',', $row[3]);
$artist_names = explode(',', $row[4]);

foreach($artist_ids as $index => $id)
    echo '<a href="artist.php?id='. $id .'">'. $artist_names[$index] .'</a>';
```

You should really use the assoc fetch mode so you can reference the columns by their names from the query - it'll make your code far more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :) Sorry if this seems a basic question. I understand how the $_GET['id'] sets the id parameter once you're on the following page (artist.php in this case) but how does this work if it's on the actual index page that the artist.php?id= links are on?

Comment: Thanks so much. It works perfectly! :) Yes, I've also changed to names as well. Like you say, it's easier to read. Thanks again for the help... much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ok really quickly, your get url artist.php?id=1,2,3 is a string, you want this to become an array. you use EXPLODE()

```
<a href="artist.php?id='.$row[3].'">'.$row[4].'</a>

$whatiwant = $_GET['id'];
$whatiwant = explode($whatiwant, ',')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :) Sorry if this seems a basic question. I understand how the $_GET['id'] sets the id parameter once you're on the following page (artist.php in this case) but how does this work if it's on the actual index page that the php?id= links are on?

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL QUERY you are concatenating the ids , when you want them as separate ids in PHP. First you should try without concatenating the artis_id  by omitting "group_concat(a.artist_id) as artist_ids" and using a.artist_id as artist_id , the second part(as artist_id) doesnt matter much if you are accessing it like $row[4].

But if you must concatenate at SQL QUERY, then you can use explode as mentioned in the other answers. but then you need to add more logic to manage which id should be mapped to what link.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! :) Yes, I've tried without the concatenate but when the specific song in the row has more than one artist (ARTIST 1 Featuring ARTIST 2 for example) I can't display them separately then. Ideally this way you can have an ID to click on for each artist rather than one as a whole. artist.php?id=1 would then link to a list of other ARTIST 1 songs and artist.php?id=2 to ARTIST 2.